# При помощи 2 указателей на массив узнать сумму

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

*Я не могу сделать указатель на начало и конец массива,что такое указатель в принципе понимаю(Не откажусь от дополнительной информаций) но как проходиться при помощи цикла по массиву понять пока не могу,вот код и он не работает,хотя я и разыменовывал,пытался через i,по адресам пробывал*

**Один массив должен указывать на начало а другой на конец и двигаться к друг другу**

```
const int size = 10;
int mas[size];
int* str = &mas[0];
int* end = &mas[10];
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    mas[i] = rand() % 10;
    cout << mas[i] << endl;
}

for (int i = str[0], j = end[10]; i < size/2; i++, j--) {
    sum += *str + *end;
}
cout << sum;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да все просто -

```
const int size = 10;
int mas[size];
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    mas[i] = rand() % 10;
    cout << mas[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;

int *str, *end;
for(str = &mas[0], end = &mas[size-1];
    str < end; ++str, --end)
    sum += *str + *end;

if (str == end) sum += *str;

cout << sum << endl;
```